# Camera rotation in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, opencv3.0

I am new to Java and Android and try to develop an application with opencv and camera preview. My problem is that the image does not follow the camera's rotation as in the images below. In the native camera and other applications this does not happen. Can anyone explain and point me in the right direction?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The native camera app ignores device rotation. Usually it uses fixed landscape orientation and hides the system UI. It may simulate screen rotation by listening to orientation sensor and rotating the on-screen buttons.

Comment: I cannot explain the last picture. The device seems to be in same landscape orientation as on the first picture, but the camera is upside down. How did you achieve this?